# Resolve enum from a custom attribute property search

Tags: c#, botframework

I have the following enum used in CallForm FormDialog:

```
public enum CallTimeOptions
{
    [Describe("tonight")]
    [Terms("tonight", "this evening", "pm", "this pm")]
    Tonight = 1,

    [Describe("tomorrow morning")]
    [Terms("tomorrow morning", "tomorrow am", "am")]
    TomorrowMorning,

    [Describe("tomorrow noon time")]
    [Terms("tomorrow noon time", "tomorrow noon", "tomorrow lunch", "lunch")]
    TomorrowNoonTime,

    [Describe("tomorrow evening")]
    [Terms("tomorrow evening", "tomorrow pm", "tomorrow night")]
    TomorrowEvening

};
```

I am calling my CallForm from a LUIS intent that can have a datetimeV2 so something like this:

```
[LuisIntent("Call")]
public async Task Call(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    EntityRecommendation entityRecommendation;

    if (result.TryFindEntity("builtin.datetimeV2.datetimerange", out entityRecommendation))
    {
        context.UserData.SetValue<string>(ContextKeys.CallTimeOption, entityRecommendation.Entity);

    }   

    context.UserData.Call(new CallForm(), CallFormResumeAfter);          
}
```

Then I want to prefill it in StartAsync of CallForm but don't know how...

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
    var state = new CallTimeForm();           
    string calltime;

    if(context.UserData.TryGetValue(ContextKeys.CallTimeOption, out calltime))
    {
        state.PreferredCallTime = -- is there a way to match calltime with CallTimeOptions ? --
    }

     var form = new FormDialog<CallTimeForm>(
                                  state,
                                  BuildForm,
                                  FormOptions.PromptInStart);

        context.Call(form, this.AfterBuildForm);
}
```

Comment: Could you reverse it like so - CallTimeOptions option = (CallTimeOptions) Enum.Parse(typeof(CallTimeOptions), calltime);

Comment: No, it throws this error `Failed with error: System.ArgumentException: Requested value ‘tomorrow night’ was not found.`

Comment: This is hard to understand what you are wanting, do you want to resolve and enum from a parameter in its attribute?

Comment: @Saruman that sounds about right. There is an extension ("Terms") of enum in Bot FormDialog. That works normally - so if I talk to the bot and say "tomorrow night" instead of clicking on "TomorrowEvening" from the list, it matches it correctly. I want to skip asking that question altogether in the bot if the user already said it in its utterance.

Comment: @Oyen, how did you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of how to do this is via reflection and [`Attribute.GetCustomAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.getcustomattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Retrieves a custom attribute of a specified type applied to an
>   assembly, module, type member, or method parameter.

**method**

```
public static class EnumEx
{
   public static T GetValueFromTerms<T>(string value)
   {
      var type = typeof(T);
      if (!type.IsEnum)
      {
         throw new InvalidOperationException();
      }

      foreach (var field in type.GetFields())
      {
         if (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(TermsAttribute)) is TermsAttribute attribute)
         {
            // Search your attribute array or properties here
            // Depending on the structure of your attribute 
            // you will need to change this if Conidition
            if (attribute.ContainsTerms(value))
            {
               return (T)field.GetValue(null);
            }
         }
         else
         {
            if (field.Name == value)
            {
               return (T)field.GetValue(null);
            }
         }
      }
      throw new ArgumentException("Not found.", nameof(value));
      // or return default(T);
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var callTimeOptions = EnumEx.GetValueFromTerms<CallTimeOptions>("tomorrow noon time");
```

However, I think you are not going about this the right way.

A more future proofed system would be to use a `Dictionary<string,CallTimeOptions>` to look up search terms and map them to enums.

I know attributes seems neat and might work well if you arnt going to expand this much, however a dictionary could be loaded form db or file, and it might just be easier to maintain (depending on your requirements)

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do it in the Bot FormDialogs-kind-of-way. I didn't want a Dictionary because I do use the Terms in the forms and I don't want to maintain two lists. If there will be no other suggestion in the next couple of days, I will mark this as answer.

Comment: @oyen using that extension method you can use the attributes

Comment: That worked well for me. The final fix on the code was `var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(TermsAttribute));
                if (attribute is TermsAttribute)
                {
                    if (((TermsAttribute)attribute).Alternatives.Contains(value))
                    {
                        return (T)field.GetValue(null);
                    }
                }`

Comment: We don't call `GetValueFromTerms` an `Extension Method.` _an extension method is a static method of a static class, where the "this" modifier is applied to the first parameter._